# Netcode how to call methods from client to client

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a code that lays out this damage dealing

```
                if (health.statusStorage.ClientStatus()) // if client
                {
                    health.GetDamageServerRpc(damage, new ServerRpcParams());
                }

                if (health.statusStorage.HostStatus()) //if host
                {
                    health.GetDamageClientRpc(damage, new ClientRpcParams());
                }
```

the code that accepts the call

```
    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void GetDamageServerRpc(int Damage, ServerRpcParams ServerRpcParams)
    {
        basicHealth.healthParts[healthPartsNumber].Value -= Damage;
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void GetDamageClientRpc(int Damage, ClientRpcParams ClientRpcParams)
    {
        basicHealth.healthParts[healthPartsNumber].Value -= Damage;
    }
```

**It works fine if it's between host and client but client to client can't damage each other, how can I make it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A: Within the `GetDamageServerRpc` also forward/relay the call to all clients via `GetDamageClientRpc` so it happens there as well.

I wonder though how exactly you ensure that `healthPartsNumber` is also the correct one on all clients.

Note that this is mostly useful for events that happen and then are over.

---

Option B: Rather use [Network variables](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/networkvariable) - especially when joining later on is a potential use case! This is more suitable if you are not dealing with a specific event but rather game information/data which seems pretty much the case here.

See [RPC vs NetworkVariables](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/learn/rpcvnetvar)

For your specific case there is even a (community contributed) [NetworkDictionary](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer-community-contributions/tree/main/com.community.netcode.extensions/Runtime/NetworkDictionary) which might just fit your case perfectly!

Comment: ```    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void GetDamageServerRpc(int Damage, ServerRpcParams ServerRpcParams)
    {
        // basicHealth.healthParts[healthPartsNumber].Value -= Damage;
        GetDamageClientRpc(Damage, new ClientRpcParams());
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void GetDamageClientRpc(int Damage, ClientRpcParams ClientRpcParams)
    {
        basicHealth.healthParts[healthPartsNumber].Value -= Damage;
    }```

Its works, thank you